# Will killing a large InnoDB rollback hurt my tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb, rollback

Using phpMyAdmin's "Copy Database" feature, I started copying one database with ~5M rows to another on the same server. About halfway through (2 hours or so) the server started crashing, and I had to kill the `mysqld` process.

MySQL is killing my server right now trying to roll back the tables that it had already started before I killed the process. It's been running for over 50 minutes now and slowing everything down.

Using `show engine innodb status` I was able to find the process no. Should I kill this process? **Will it hurt my tables, or hurt anything, or is it safe to stop the rollback?**

Here's the entry. At it's current rate, it looks like it'll take about 3 more hours to finish the 983k log entries left.

`---TRANSACTION 0 1853619464, ACTIVE 3214 sec, process no 5552, OS thread id 3028249488
ROLLING BACK , undo log entries 983813`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you kill your rollback, it'll just do the rollback again the next time.  It must complete the rollback to get the tables back to a consistent state.

Comment: It actually looks like it'll take about 5 hours to finish rolling back. It may be less time to just restore the entire DB from a backup (done just a few hours prior). Can I kill the rollback and drop the database right away?

Comment: I don't think that'll work.  Do you have a backup of all databases on this server?  If so, it'll be faster to kill mysqld and delete/reinitialize its data directory, then do a restore.

Comment: Looks like the backup from yesterday never actually finished due to a collision with this copy, so we are just going to have it wait it out. Thanks!